# Numpy select by string from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to create a new column in my pandas DataFrame based on matching strings. I have pathnames of images that contain either the string `'distorted'` or `'original'`. I would like to assign the string values `'d'` and `'o'` in the new column respectively. I have been using `np.select` but I got a shape-mismatch error.

This is my code:

```
type_cond = [(df[df['img_name'].str.contains(r'\bdistorted\b')]), (df[df['img_name'].str.contains(r'\boriginal\b')])]

type_values = ['d', 'o']

df['image_type'] = np.select(type_cond, type_values)
```

When I run the conditions separately, I get the expected output:

```
distorted = df[df['img_name'].str.contains(r'\bdistorted\b')]
```

output:

| id | n | r | img_name | rid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 2995 | I | 2 | images/distorted/png/3MRNMEIQW56USS7S1XTZ20C8J... | E |
| 2996 | I | 3 | images/distorted/png/30MVJZJNHMDCUC6BMWCK0PGQO... | E |
| 2997 | I | 2 | images/distorted/png/3MYYFCXHJ37164AYXVVQM4DUA... | E |
| 2998 | I | 3 | images/distorted/png/39RP059MEHTLJDRTND387N3XG... | E |
| 2999 | I | 1 | images/distorted/png/3EKVH9QMEY4OR6LKRRBUN4DZD... | E |

[2003 rows x 4 columns]

When filtering the strings that contain `'original'` it selects: [997 rows x 4 columns]

The entire data frame is of size: [3000 rows x 4 columns]

I don't see why there is a shape mismatch because all the rows are covered by either condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in conditions list are filtered DataFrames.

So need remove [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - (`df[]`):

```
type_cond = [df['img_name'].str.contains(r'\bdistorted\b'),
             df['img_name'].str.contains(r'\boriginal\b')]
```